# Scrolling a QTreeWidget with gestures

Tags: python, pyqt, scrollbar, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I am writing a program in Python 3.5 and PyQt5. I have a QTreeWidget that has a list of items in it. I want to hide the scrollbar and make touch scrolling for it in the vertical direction. This is my code:

```
    self.category_tree = QTreeWidget(self.framemain)
    self.category_tree.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.category_tree.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.category_tree.setGeometry(QRect(630, 90, 161, 381))
    self.category_tree.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)
    self.category_tree.setLocale(QLocale(QLocale.Persian, QLocale.Iran))
    self.category_tree.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    self.category_tree.setUniformRowHeights(False)
    self.category_tree.setColumnCount(1)
    self.category_tree.setObjectName("category_tree")
    self.category_tree.headerItem().setText(0, "1")
    self.category_tree.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
    self.category_tree.header().setVisible(False)
    self.category_tree.header().setSortIndicatorShown(False)
    self.category_tree.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
    self.category_tree.verticalScrollBar().setSingleStep(25)

def checkscroll(self,startx,endx):
    if (startx - endx) >= 25:
    #swipe from right to left
        self.category_tree.verticalScrollBar().setSliderPosition(self.category_tree.verticalScrollBar().sliderPosition()+(25))
    elif (startx - endx) <= -25:
            self.category_tree.verticalScrollBar().setSliderPosition(self.category_tree.verticalScrollBar().sliderPosition()-abs(25))
```

The problem is that when I swipe on the QTreeWidget to make it scroll it goes to the end or start of the view and doesn't scroll normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use the [QScroller](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscroller.html#details) class for this. It seems that something like this should work:

```
QScroller.grabGesture(self.category_tree.viewport(), QScroller.TouchGesture)
```

However, I cannot test this myself, so you may need to experiment a bit to get the behaviour you want.

**UPDATE**:

You may also need to change the vertical scroll mode:

```
self.category_tree.setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)
```

Comment: Hello, it doesn't make any difference still when touching it goes to last or first item suddenly and when I use QScroller it makes another problem that is dragging the widget itself when it reaches end of the list and it makes a very bad view,

Comment: @Nimda. I'm fairly sure that `QScroller` is what you need. Can you try with `Qt.LeftMouseButtonGesture` instead of `Qt.TouchGesture`?

Comment: @Nimda. See my updated answer for another thing to try (with or without the `QScroller`).

Comment: Thank you a lot. I used `Qt.LeftMouseButtonGesture` and `ScrollPerPixel` and it works like a charm!